# Prevent laravel message to be displayed and redirect the user to custom page issue in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to catch somehow the laravel error, warning message. I don't want to disable them from the config/app.php file.  I am using monolog to log some information. 
This is my piece of code:

```
public function view($id){
   try {
     $tag = Tags::find(12313);   // tags is a model
   }catch(Exception $error){
        echo 'error'; exit();
        $this->log->logMessage(Logger::ERROR, $error->getMessage());
        return redirect()->route('admin.tags')->with(['msg' => 'Smth went wrong']);
   }
}
```

`$this->log` is a class where I am using the `monolog class` to log information.

The fact is that right now , it doesn't go to the catch part . I don't get the `error` message. I'm getting this message from laravel:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: ......
```

I intentionally put the number `12313` there to see if it is working or not. And for some reason is not working and I am not redirected . The idea, if something happened I want to redirect the user to a specific page with a general error message. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: can you show log  class if this is your own class

Comment: @iCoders it doesn't matter the content of my log class, as you can see I don't get the `error` message before the `exit()` function :)

Comment: I am not looking for a specific case, I would like to have a general case to catch all laravel error message and redirect the user to a specific page. This is just an example of those many cases :)

Comment: @chester.ya now i got it .thanks for the comment

Comment: @iCoders , ok , is that possible ? :)

Comment: ya you can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in laravel .You can handle erors in App\Exceptions\Handler class

```
  public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

        if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
           return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }
          if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
        {
                return response()->view('errors.405', [], 405);

        }
         if($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException)
        {

           return response()->view('errors.404', [], 405);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: and where should I add this function ?

Comment: if you check  in App\Exceptions\ folders in your laravel .you have Handler  class file

Comment: app -> Exceptions-> handler.php

Comment: also if you want to log errors then you can follow Alex answer

Comment: @Chester.glad to here this helped you

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method doesn't throw an exception if the record is not found. So do this instead:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $tag = Tags::find(12313);   // tags is a model

    if (is_null($tag)) {
        $this->log->logMessage(Logger::ERROR, $error->getMessage());
        return redirect()->route('admin.tags')->with(['msg' => 'Smth went wrong']);
    }
}
```

Or use [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) which will throw an exception if specified record is not found.

> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown